# Location of SHA512 Haslist on Mavericks>

Tags: encryption, passwords, hashing, macos, terminal

I'm trying to find the SHA512 hash of the user passwords on OS X Mavericks (10.9.1), I'm aware that you can get the user .plist from:

> /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/{username}.plist

if the user has used SMB then a SHA1 representation of their password will be stored here however this does not contain the native SHA512 hash.

Everything I've read suggest that the has can be found at:

> /var/db/shadow/hash/{guid}

However when I try to navigate to this directory I can only get as far as

> /var/db/

once I get here and try to cd into shadow OS X tells me:

[image]

**Does anyone know where I can find the SHA512 hash of the user password on Mavericks?**

Answer (score 1):

Several versions ago, Apple switched from SHA512 hashes to a more secure [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) hash (based on SHA512, but iterating it many times). As a result, the SHA512 hash doesn't exist any more.